# Could this be a memory leak?

Tags: c++, c++11

Does using a new then setting to null cause memory leaks?

Ive tried the following code but have no idea if it causes any leak or not

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   int* x = new int;
   int y = 1;
   x = &y;

   x = nullptr; // has the memory allocated to x gone now?

   x =&y;       // did i recover what was lost?

   delete x;   

   return 0;
}
```

// the cout<<*x gives 1 as expected

Comment: Yes, this is a leak.

Comment: `x = nullptr; // has the memory allocated to x gone now?` - No. You did not `delete` what you `new`ed. You just set the value of a pointer variable to zero , so it no longer points to the object, but the object itself is still alive.

Comment: `x =&y; 

   delete x;` - That's a bug. You `delete` the address of `y`, but `y` was never allocated with `new`. Undefined behaviour - in many cases a crash (but that's not guaranteed).

Comment: "Could this be a memory leak?" - it is that and several other bugs.

Comment: so never use 'delete' without 'new' is the rule.
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a leak. However, the leak does not occur when you assigned `nullptr` to `x`, but rather in the line before it:

```cpp
x = &y;
```

`x` now points to the address of `y`, and no other references to the memory you allocated with `new int` exist. Without any references to that memory, there's no way to deallocate it.

Comment: thanks a lot  for the feedback, so something dynamically created must always follow a delete if its address is to be changed to some other object so a leak doesnt occur.

Answer (score 1):

The pointed-to-object is lost when you assign to the only pointer that holds it. As stated above, `x = &y` already loses your `new int`. Nothing you do afterwards can bring it back. This means that the `delete` invokes undefined behaviour and might crash your program.

However, there is a mechanism in C++ that avoids such memory leaks: Smart Pointers.

In C++ smart pointers come in two main varieties `::std::unique_ptr<T>` and `::std::shared_ptr<T>`. They have the job of holding on to an object in dynamic memory and make sure to delete it when it becomes unowned:

```
::std::unique_ptr<int> x = ::std::make_unique<int>(0);
x = nullptr; // automatically deletes the previously allocated int
```

This is slightly more expensive than raw pointers but it is less prone to memory leaks. Smart pointers live in the <[memory](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory)> header.

Comment: very informative thanks, so  the new created int should only be used like 

int* x = new int;

*x = 2 say 

or int y = *x 
etc 


those smart pointers seem to be like  mini garbage collectors perhaps?!

Comment: @AfzelAdam They are similar to garbage collection, except they are not broken rubbish. Your statement about how to use the raw pointer appears to be correct. But the use of raw pointers in modern C++ is extremely limited. You should pretty much never use them.